# when a setOnTouchListener is set to webview - loadDataWithBaseURL does not work or shows the same old content

Tags: android, webview, touch, listener

I am loading some sequence of pages while the user swipes/flings on the webview, using the animation effect of the viewflipper - to bring that iphone transition effect.

I have two webviews added to a viewflipper.

Added setOnTouchListener to both the webviews and using gesture detector for fling.

After detecting the fling direction, I am setting the next/previous page and then calling the flipper's shownext/showprevious.

What happens is that the webview is not showing the content whatever that I pass through loadDataWithBaseURL ? - it shows the old content.

If I remove the touch listener(setOnTouchListener), and add a button to navigate, then the same process/logic works.

My code is similar to this one - http://pastie.org/1065119.txt

why this is happening ? could anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found that if I return false on the method onFling of the GestureDetector instead of returning true, the data in the webview gets updated on every swipe. 
When returning true, it seems to only display the cache of the data that is used for the webview. Hope this helps with your issue also.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively return always false in implemented method onTouch(), registered by WebView.setOnTouchListener(). This way you change the behaviour for WebView only, while onFling() continues to return the correct value for other views (such as the activity in the example).